# How to use pto_header in RML?

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7, rml

I did a report, which was working perfect, but I realized that when there are several pages, the header and the footer were being shown only in the first page.

So I started to use `<pto>`, `<pto_header>` and `<pto_trailer>`. But these are not working as expected. For example, when I only use `pto_header`:

```
<story>
    <pto>
        <pto_header>
            <para style="P1">
                <font color="white"> </font>
            </para>
            <blockTable colWidths="480.0" style="Table1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <para style="header_td">My column</para>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </blockTable>
        </pto_header>
        <blockTable colWidths="480.0" style="Table2">
            <tr>
                <para style="terp_default_8">[[ repeatIn(objects,'o') ]]</para>
                <para style="terp_default_8">[[ setLang(o.lang) ]]</para>
                <td>
                    <para>[[ o.name or '' ]]</para>
                    <para>
                        <font color="white"> </font>
                    </para>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </blockTable>
    </pto>
</story>
```

The result is that the section I declared as the `pto_header` is only being shown at the last page of the report. And if I declare a `pto_trailer` the result is the other way round. The `pto_trailer` is only shown at the very first page.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this might be helpful to you.

```
<story>
<pto>
    <pto_header>
        <para style="P1">
            <font color="white"> </font>
        </para>
        <blockTable colWidths="480.0" style="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <para style="header_td">My column</para>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </blockTable>
    </pto_header>
    <para style="terp_default_8">[[ repeatIn(objects,'o') ]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_8">[[ setLang(o.lang) ]]</para>
     <blockTable colWidths="480.0" style="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <para style="header_td">My column</para>
                </td>
            </tr>
     </blockTable>
    <blockTable colWidths="480.0" style="Table2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <para>[[ o.name or '' ]]</para>
                <para>
                    <font color="white"> </font>
                </para>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </blockTable>
</pto>          
</story>
```

Comment: Great @Odedra!! This is working. Just one question: if I paste your code without modifications, the pto_header is working well but there is only one record being shown by page (so the report has a lot of pages). I have to put the paras with repeatIn and setLang like I had before, inside the Table2. Do you know why?

Comment: As per number of ids, it will print a separate document for each. And for standard use of `<pto_header>` is given in an answer. Also make sure this two line are come after `</pto_header>` finished. 1. repeatin and 2. setlang. Never put this 2 tag in any block table. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But if I want to emulate the tree view of the object in the report, what I am doing would be right, wouldn't it?

Comment: if you want tree view than no need put in repeatIn in a blocktable. It will printed document. And try above code for in tree view that will be printed your tree view object.